# How to get a selected item from a Spinner in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner

I tried

`lateinit var newOrderStatus: Spinner`

`newOrderStatus = findViewById(R.id.spn_order_change_status).text.toString()`

also

`lateinit var newOrderStatus: Spinner`

`newOrderStatus = spn_order_change_status.selectedItem()`

Nothing worked.

The situation is that. I have a `spinner`, `textView` and a `button` on a fragment. When I hit the button, I want the selected value in the spinner to be updated in the `firestore`. I have created a function in my `FirestoreClass.kt`. This `fun` takes two arguments, one from the spinner and the other from the textView. The value from the spinner is the new value for the field 'status' and the value from the textView is the name of the document in the firestore. How can I pass these values of textView and Spinner to the fun I have in `FirestoreClass.kt`? Where to write these codes.
I have `OrderStatusListAdapter.kt` , `OrdersByStatusFragment.kt` files. and the button and spinner are on the `order_status_layout.xml`

Comment: Can you give more details, such as compiler error messages or logs?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Unresolved reference `findViewById`